# Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that $\cos(x)=x^3$ has a solution.

Tags: calculus

I am not sure if I am fully understanding how to solve this, but I think that, since the since $g(x)=\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=x^3$ are continuous everywhere, the function $f(x)=\cos(x)-x^3$ must also be continuous everywhere, and therefore, according to the Intermediate Value Theorem, $\cos(x)=x^3$ must have a solution. However, I'm not sure if that's true.

How can I show that $\cos(x)=x^3$ has a solution?

Comment: You need to find points $y,z$ where $f(y) > 0$ and $f(z) < 0$. Then by the intermediate value theorem, there is a point $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Observe that $f(0) = 1 > 0$, while $f(\pi) = -1 - \pi^3 < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $f(x)$ is continuous and hence satisfies the IVT, AND it is negative at say $x=\pi$, AND it is positive at say $x=0$, we know that between those two x values $f(x)=0$.

Comment: By $f(x)$ do you mean $\cos(x)-x^3$?

Comment: @LuminousNutria yes, as you have in your question

Comment: I see, thank you!